# Custom font in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm new in iphone themes develop, and i want to know how to use custom TTF or OTF fonts on iphone, like one font type for phone pad, other for messages, etc...

Can help me?

Comment: Do you plan to develop applications or do you plan to develop themes that are generally usable by any application as well as the standard GUI of the iPhone? For the latter, AFAIK there is no solution available.
Note; Custom TTF/OTF capability has been publicly introduced with iOS SDK 3.2.

Comment: only for themes.... i dont have a mac to develop apps, and i dont know if the Windows aplications are good to do.... i think no...

Comment: Complete themes are something you can only do with jailbroken iPhones. Creating products for such market is like trying to sell stuff to a thief => very unlikely to be a commercial success. And no, I am not saying that jailbreaking was a crime or compareable to a breach of any of the ten commandmends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can easily use custom TTF fonts in your application. All you need to do is to [add the font as a resource and set a key in your Info.plist](http://blog.beefyapps.com/2010/06/custom-fonts-in-ios-4/).

See also [this step-by-step guide](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/).

Comment: +1 for best solution available if you want to support iOS >= 3.2

Comment: huumm.. my iphone is FW 3.1.2, so i think i cant use these custom fonts..., any way to change fonts? or not.. ?

Comment: @Preston: See the first link in @PengOne's answer.